# git: how to maintain 2 branches and update 1 according to another?

Tags: git

For example, I have two branches, `clean` and `debug`, the difference is in `debug` branch, there is a `print $global.watch` in every functions , while there's no such thing in the `clean` branch.

basically i develop in `debug` branch, and from time to time, I'd like to update the changes from `debug` to `clean`, how can I do this? Apparently I cannot do a `merge`

Comment: In my opinion, it is not the question about git (or any version control system), but about the approach. Your code base should contains mechanisms to enable/disable debug mode for your needs. For now,  you are working on two different codes - what, if those prints introduce some delays in your debug system, and it works because of it? For those logs, you should rather work on configurable log levels. As long, as it somehow make your code less readable, maybe use some kind of annotations, to rid out of unnecessary lines.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Debugging should be manageable using a switch of some kind. Not by manually commenting out lines from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem where I need to use some dummy data.
What i do is use stash which basically save changes locally to be applied on any branch later. What you need to do is:

1. go to your debug branch
2. remove all the prints in the code
3. instead of committing the changes, stash them. This will save the print(less) code locally into a stash and return the debug code to its initial state.
4. stashes can have names and are saved locally, so each time you need to merge the debug branch into clean branch apply the stash to remove the print.

details on how to stash your changes check this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-stash)

Comment: This is tedious and doesn't really solve the problem. Step 2 will be time consuming.

Comment: Currently OP will have to do step 2 if he wants to merge the debug branch into the clean one. With my suggested way he will only need to do it once.

Comment: What about changes that the OP makes  on the debug after stashing? It might not cleanly apply back after modifications. There is a possibility of a merge conflict each time.

Answer (score 0):

Even your code base should contains mechanisms to debug when you need it. I think you can use git cherry-pick.

Procedure:

1. Do a commit in one of your branch. Copy the commit-hash
2. Move to the other branch and `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`